# coldfusion server monitor jvm snapshots

Tags: crash, jvm, coldfusion-8, logfiles, jvm-crash

one my server instances has started to go haywire in a multi-instance setup running adobe coldfusion 8.1 enterprise. the built in cf server monitor is throwing these alert snapshots constantly, however, this same box is running Fusion Reactor {http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/} and I can not figure out where they are coming from.  anyone have any pointers or a good tool to decode these files?

full link: http://pastebin.com/42M2Nzpj

```
"CM Configuration Updater" prio=5 tid=82 WAITING
     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
     at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:76)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"AWT-Windows" prio=6 tid=299 RUNNABLE
     at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
     at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:293)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"Signal Dispatcher" prio=9 tid=5 RUNNABLE

"Timer-3" prio=5 tid=67 TIMED_WAITING
     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

"scheduler-4" prio=5 tid=36 TIMED_WAITING
     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
     at jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService.createRunnable(SchedulerService.java:188)
     at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.createRunnable(ThreadPool.java:349)
     at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:62)

"jrpp-145" prio=5 tid=11622 RUNNABLE
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
     at jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readFully(ProxyEndpoint.java:581)
     at jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readFully(ProxyEndpoint.java:573)
     at jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readInt(ProxyEndpoint.java:591)
     at jrun.servlet.jrpp.ProxyEndpoint.readRequest(ProxyEndpoint.java:231)
     at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.swapRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:143)
     at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.swapRunnable(ThreadPool.java:410)
     at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:76)
```

Comment: Please do not post "additions" to your question as answers. Nobody is going to read a logfile that long anyway.

Comment: Please cut this down to the relevant information and edit your log file into the question.

Comment: did you actually read the question? if you did, you will notice I am asking how to interpret these?  if anyone has a solid understanding of how.  it is directly programming related and I had no other way of posting a long text log, b/c the entire log file in coldfusion is reviewed, not just a piece.  have you worked with cf jvm logs before?  can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have an snapshot/alert set to collect a snapshot file when your JVM allocates more than 1000 megabytes of memory. This is probably not a great idea since under normal circumstances your Jvm might indeed allocate that much and recover with a GC.  I would look at your alert/snapshot settings and adjust them.

Comment: I have re-tooled them to 2GB since the server has a good chunk of memory and each of the 3 instances are allocated a max or 2.  Have you seen any tools out there to interpret these logs? something that decodes them into a more readable thread format with indicators as to what the threads i.e. pages they could have corresponded to?

Comment: Chris, They are pretty readable as java logs and traces go (ha). Most of the stack trace can be ignored most of the time. I kind of of focus on the request stats and the JVM memory stuff when I'm troubleshooting. Sometimes you find a pattern of threads in the stack trace that hints at something to investigate - but the one you posted looked pretty normal as me. FusionReactor and even the built in CF monitor are interpreting the same data though.

Comment: Is there anyway to correlate the IDs to a page? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes there is... that's exactly what fusionreactor is doing in real time when you view active requests - but to analyze a stack trace you would need a history of JRPP numbers and those numbers are reused - so it would be a daunting task to do it after the fact.

Comment: bummer, I see what you are saying now.  thanks for your help on this